# issue with passing logon user information to javascript

Tags: javascript

I have checkbox which when the user click on it, it will pass the logon user information to a JavaScript function

```
 <input class="mybox" type="checkbox" name ="myf[]" value="<%=results_rs("id")%>" onchange="myfc('<%=request.servervariables("LOGON_USER")%>')">
```

JavaScript function:-

```
 <script >

     function myfc(cb) {
     alert(cb)
 </script>
```

my issue is the logon user string is something like this: mydomainname\john.smith

when it pass to the function, the \ is missing for some reason. could you please help?

Comment: `\ ` is often an escape character. Does using `\\ ` instead work around the issue? (Funny, even writing this comment, I had an issue with `\ ` being treated as escape character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `\` with `\\` to escape it

```
 onchange="myfc('<%= request.servervariables("LOGON_USER").replace("\","\\") %>'"
```

Comment: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6' 

Object doesn't support this property or method: 'REPLACE'
I've go this error message on my page. sorry.